# Fullcalendar give the cell background color dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, calendar, fullcalendar

There is a fuvar_status field in my sql table. Now, the fullcalendar cells have a static color.

What i want is: if the fuvar_status is 0, the background will be #ff0000, or the fuvar_status is 1, the bg will be an another color.

How to write this in the, and javascript file?

My php, that gets the records from sql:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

$sql = 
"
    SELECT 

        fuvar.fuvar_id,
        fuvar.fuvar_date,
        fuvar.fuvar_status,
        fuvar.fuvar_kerulet,
        gyarto.gyarto_nev,
        Varosok.VarosNev

    FROM fuvar

    LEFT JOIN gyarto ON fuvar.fuvar_honnan = gyarto.gyarto_id
    LEFT JOIN Varosok ON fuvar.fuvar_hova = Varosok.VarosID

    LIMIT 50

";

// WHERE status != Lezárt fuvar 

$get = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die("SQL ERROR 1 - " . mysqli_error($kapcs));
if(mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 )
{
    $VarosNev = array();
    $gyarto_nev = array();
    $fuvar_date = array();
    $fuvar_id = array();

    while( $e = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
    {
        if($e['fuvar_kerulet'] == "0" ) { $VarosNev[] = $e['VarosNev']; }
        else { $VarosNev[] = $e['VarosNev'] .' '. $e['fuvar_kerulet']; }

        $gyarto_nev[] = $e['gyarto_nev'];
        $fuvar_date[] = $e['fuvar_date'];
        $fuvar_id[] = $e['fuvar_id'];
    }
    $res = array
    (
        'VarosNev' => $VarosNev,
        'gyarto_nev' => $gyarto_nev, 
        'fuvar_date' => $fuvar_date, 
        'fuvar_id' => $fuvar_id,
    );
    echo json_encode($res);
}
?>
```

Javascript, generate events:

```
for (i = 0; i < hossz; i++) 
            {
                if (eventArray.fuvar_id[i] != '') 
                {
                    valami.push({
                        title: eventArray.gyarto_nev[i] +'\n'+eventArray.VarosNev[i],
                        backgroundColor: '#03674e',
                        start: eventArray.fuvar_date[i],
                        url: '/fuvar-szerkesztes/' + eventArray.fuvar_id[i]
                    });
                } 
                else 
                {
                    valami.push({
                        title: eventArray.gyarto_nev[i] +'\n'+eventArray.VarosNev[i],
                        backgroundColor: '#03674e',
                        start: eventArray.fuvar_date[i],
                    });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no particular reason to do half of your processing in PHP and half in JavaScript. You could just make what PHP produces compatible with fullCalendar. You've also using a bizarre arrangement of redundant parallel arrays in PHP, and then relying on the index values to match the values up. Perhaps you aren't aware of PHP's support for associative arrays? You can do it all with one array to create actual events, directly:

```
$get = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die("SQL ERROR 1 - " . mysqli_error($kapcs));

if(mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0 )
{
  $events = array();

  while( $e = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
  {
    $VarosNev = ($e['fuvar_kerulet'] == "0" ? $e['VarosNev'] :  $e['fuvar_kerulet']);

    $evt = array(
      "title" => $e['gyarto_nev']."\n".$VarosNev,
      "backgroundColor" => ($e["fuvar_status"] == 0 ? "#ff0000" : "#03674e"),
      "start": $e["fuvar_date"]
    );

    if ($e['fuvar_id'] != "") { $evt["url"] = "/fuvar-szerkesztes/".$e["fuvar_id"]; }

    $events[] = $evt;
  }

  echo json_encode($events);
}
```

Then you shouldn't need the `for` loop in JavaScript at all - you can just send the JSON from the server direct into fullCalendar.

N.B. Obviously I could not test this fully without your data, so apologies for any small errors - point them out if you can't fix them and I will amend the answer if necessary.

Comment: Can i echo out the bg color code into the javascript code?

Comment: why would you need to do that, exactly? Like I said, your javascript loop is made redundant by this re-wrote. But yes in theory once you get the events from your ajax request they are JS objects, so you can write code to access the `backgroundColor` property of any single event, just like any other JS object.

Comment: why not? This is saving you loads of redundant code, and I already wrote it for you. Try it, at least? You'd still have to change a reasonable amount to do it the other way - right now your server isn't outputting the status variable, and then you'd need to change the javascript as well.